# Text align to image width

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have the text align to the right and left side of the image without wrapping or overflowing? With the current code below the text doesn't align to the edges and can either end up being too small or too big depending on user settings.

```
.logo-table {
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 195px;
}

.logotext {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerlogo {
    width: 195px;
}


<div class="logo-table">



<img src="/images/header.png" class="headerlogo" align="middle">


      <p class="logotext">Neque porro quisquam est</p></td>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` will align the text to either side of the element, so this will work for your case.

I added `text-align-last: center;` so the text is centered as well - also the `.headerlogo` should have width 100%, so you don't have to write it two times.

```css
.logo-table {
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.logotext {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: center;
}

.headerlogo {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-table">
  <img src="https://csswizardry.com/logo.png" class="headerlogo" align="middle">
  <p class="logotext">Neque porro quis quam est</p>
</div>
```